# Trouble in calculated column over date range in Power Pivot using DAX expression

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot

As per application need, Need to do below task in Power Pivot report. (Not in SQL).

I have two date columns in one table

**Column Hears** :

```
 /* Column Heads :*/   Activity| City |  Start_Date  |  End_Date

  /*  Row 1 :*/           A1   |  C1  |  01/01/2014  |  05/01/2014

  /*  Row 2 :*/           A1   |  C1  |  06/01/2014  |  07/01/2014

  /*  Row 3 : */          A2   |  C2  |  06/01/2014  |  07/01/2014

  /*  Row 4 : */          A3   |  C3  |  03/01/2014  |  04/01/2014
```

Expected output like - If user selects date range 02/01/2014 to 07/01/2014

**Column Header**

```
City  | #StartCount| #EndCount 

 C1   |      1     |    2   

 C2   |      1     |    1

 C3   |      1     |    1
```

Here `#StartCount` is

- Need to grouped by City.
- Its Count of Distinct Activity
- It should consider date boundries as : All activity for which start date 'greater or equeal(>=)' Input Start date and (less than '<') End Date

Here `#EndCount` is

- Need to grouped by City.
- Its Count of Distinct Activity
- It should consider date boundries as : All activity for which Ends date 'Less or equeal(<=)' Input End date and (Greater than '>') End Date

Could you please suggest me expression to be used for such case. 
Calculated measure or dax can be used..

Comment: have u tried any query from your side??

Comment: which sql product are you using ? mysql, mssql, oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerPivot Aggregated value based on groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140988/powerpivot-aggregated-value-based-on-groups)

Comment: hi, i have flagged this as a duplicate - and posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140988/powerpivot-aggregated-value-based-on-groups

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can match your sample data is to ignore the "distinct activities" requirement in your question, since city `C1` has only activity `A1` and yet the final result counts to 2.

I'm also probably making a lot of assumptions that may be wrong because your sample data is quite limited. But here's my attempt:

```
declare @Activities table (Activity char(2),City char(2),Start_Date date,End_Date date)
insert into @Activities (Activity,City,Start_Date,End_Date) values
('A1','C1','20140101','20140105'),
('A1','C1','20140106','20140107'),
('A2','C2','20140106','20140107'),
('A3','C3','20140103','20140104')

declare @Start date
declare @End date
select @Start = '20140102', @End = '20140107'

select City,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Start_Date < @Start THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as StartCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN End_Date > @End THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as EndCount
from @Activities where Start_Date < @End and End_Date > @Start
group by City
```

(Some of this relies on SQL Server syntax, but since you haven't tagged your question with a database system, I get to pick)

Comment: Could you please help me to use in Power Pivot. Or Is there is any other way to conevert SQL Query into DAX expression. Any tool available?

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` syntax

```
select activity, city, 
    SUM(case when (startdate  >= '2014/01/02' and startdate <= '2014/01/07') then 1 else 0 End) as IsStart, 
    SUM(case when (enddate  >= '2014/01/02' and enddate <='2014/01/07') then 1 else 0 End) as IsEnd
from temp
Group by  activity, city
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2a64/1

Comment: Could you please let me know the tool to convert above SQL into DAX expression to use in Power Pivot Report?