# PowerPivot Aggregated value based on groups

Tags: powerpivot

I have two date columns in one table:

| Activity | City | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | C1 | 01/01/2014 | 05/01/2014 |
| A1 | C1 | 06/01/2014 | 07/01/2014 |
| A2 | C2 | 06/01/2014 | 07/01/2014 |
| A3 | C3 | 03/01/2014 | 04/01/2014 |

Expected output like - If user selects date range 02/01/2014 to 07/01/2014

| City | #StartCount | #EndCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1 | 2 |
| C2 | 1 | 1 |
| C3 | 1 | 1 |

Here `#StartCount` is

- Need to grouped by City.
- It's count of distinct activity
- It should consider date boundaries as : All activity for which start date 'greater or equal(>=)' Input Start date and (less than '<') End Date

Here `#EndCount` is

- Need to grouped by City.
- It's count of distinct activity
- It should consider date boundaries as : All activity for which Ends date 'Less or equal(<=)' Input End date and (Greater than '>') End Date

Could you please suggest an expression to be used for such a case.
Calculated measure or dax can be used..

Answer (score 0):

The key here is using disconnected slicers, because if you used the "regular" ones, then performing the COUNT calculations won't work because they simply filter out the rows that don't "fit".

I have used your data for creating 3 tables:

- *Source* table - exactly the same as yours
- *Start* table - containing single column called *Start* that includes the start dates from *Source*
- *End* table - containing single column called *End* that includes the end dates from *Source*

Then I added two calculated fields:

**Start Count**

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTA(Source[City]),FILTER(Source,Source[Start]>=MIN('Start'[Start])))
```

**End Count**

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTA(Source[City]),FILTER(Source,Source[Start]<=MIN('End'[End])))
```

What these two commands do is that they count City rows that are not empty, and filter them by (using FILTER command) *Start* or *End* column. Read more about [disconnected slicers here](http://www.cimaglobal.com/Thought-leadership/Newsletters/Insight-e-magazine/Insight-2012/Insight-November-2012/Excel-Extras--PowerPivot-CALCULATE-with-disconnected-slicers/).

To get your report: **create a new PowerPivot table, put *City* on rows and drag *Start Count* and *End Count* to values. Then add slicers for both *Start* and *End* tables. Selected your dates and you will get the results you need.**

Attached is the screen of what I used (this will work in Excel 2013 as well as Excel 2010 with PowerPivot plugin):

[image]

Using *disconnected slicer* might be tricky sometimes -- but if you create them with newly available Excel Apps like [CreateTimeDimension](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/create-time-dimension-WA103994479.aspx) (for free) or [pre-prepared DateTables](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2011/11/the-ultimate-date-table/), you should be just fine.

Hope this helps!